# Possible omission in pronunciation of "in"

Tags: grammar

I'm learning English in an app. When I listened to the sentence

> Hats prevailed *in* the 19th century.

the word "in" is hard to identify, so I want to know: is it not pronounced?

Comment: It would be unusual to omit "in" here. Perhaps it is said rather quickly and indistinctly. Lexico's entry for [**prevail**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/prevail) states "no object". So in the sentence "Hats prevailed the 19th century" the verb would be transitive – but it isn't.

Comment: The verb "prevail" is a slightly odd choice for the context (what was the fashion for wearing hats supposedly ***victoriously struggling against**?*). But syntactically, in *Hats [were ubiquitous] **in** the 19th century,* the preposition ***in*** signifies a "container metaphor" usage (all the years from 1800 to 1899 are "in, within" that century). Same as *I don't sunbathe **in** winter*, as opposed to the "surface" metaphor for a more specific time reference: *I don't work **on** Sunday*. We *might* drop the prepositions in my examples (highly idiomatic / colloquial), but never in yours.

Comment: I often hear words run together. That sentence might be pronounced as "hats prevail-din the nineteenth century." The "din", which is two words run together, might simply sound like the ending "d" of "prevailed", thus missing the "in" entirely. Many speakers of US English tend to corrupt (run together) phrases; there are regional differences in this tendency.

Comment: @EdwardBarnard  It seems like this